# How to make html table from sql linq in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I'd like to simply add an html table to a placeholder without iterating through all the cells and rows.

My sql statement is like this, but VS is unavailable for me to debug and I'm unsure how to treat q for length/count to iterate through. I am new to this so coming up with the correct vocabulary in my head of how to search this solution is difficult.

Is there a simple linq statement to put this in a placeholder?

```
var q = from kvp2 in entityToCluster
join kvp3 in clusterToQVR on kvp2.Value equals kvp3.Key
where kvp2.Key == prim_in.ToUpper() || kvp2.Key == ref_in.ToUpper()
select new {entity = kvp2.Key, cluster = kvp2.Value, qvRule = kvp3.Value};
Console.WriteLine("column1 = {0}, column2 = {1}, column3 = {2}, q.entity, q.cluster, q.qvRule");
```

Obviously write line doesn't work to the server. Normally I:

```
        Table tbl = new Table();
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();

        (iterate through)


        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tbl);
```

If someone had a simple method to do this for any q I create that would help my learning exponentially.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GJ2KVS may help you

Comment: Why not use something like a `DataGrid` or `GridView`?

Comment: Could someone show me how to do that? dataGridView1.DataSource = q; & <asp:GridView ID="dataGridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView> isn't showing anything

Comment: Try something like var dataSource=q.ToList(); and then bind GridView to dataSource

Comment: @MarkMcGown: As @David points out, learning `GridView` ''is'' a good idea--it offers a lot of power. But I encourage you to understand how to make `Table` work first, since that will give you useful general concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting close :) Where you have "iterate through" you would use a [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) loop. In this case that would look like `foreach (var line in q)`, where `line` represents a single result of your query each time the `foreach` loop iterates.

For each iteration you'd create a new `TableRow` object, and add it to the table with `tbl.Rows.Add`.

Since your cells are based on named properties, you can't easily use a loop for those. Instead, make a line for each one to add it to your row. For example, if the `TableRow` object's name is `tableRow`, you would do this something like this for your `entity` property:

```
var entityCell = new TableCell();
entityCell.Text = line.entity.ToString();
tableRow.Cells.Add(entityCell);
```

Depending on what you want to do with the cell you might need to set other properties too. You can find a list with descriptions [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell(v=vs.110).aspx).

Is that enough to get you going?